# Take multiple images from the gallery and make a pdf

Tags: java, android, pdf

I am trying to get multiple images from the gallery and make them a PDF here is the code. In the code, I can take multiple images from the user and also make them PDF. But the PDF contains only one image even though I selected multiple images it only shows one image in pdf. I have attached the code below.

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

    bitmaps = new ArrayList < > ();
    ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();

    if (clipData != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
            try {
                Uri uri = clipData.getItemAt(i).getUri();
                InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                bitmaps.add(bitmap);

                pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();
                PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), bitmaps.size())
                    .create();

                for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
                    PdfDocument.Page page = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo);
                    Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
                    Paint paint = new Paint();
                    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                    canvas.drawPaint(paint);

                    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), true);
                    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    canvas.drawPaint(paint);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);

                    pdfDocument.finishPage(page);
                }
                bitmap.recycle();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "PDF Folder");

        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdir();
        }

        File file = new File(root, "image" + ".pdf");
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            pdfDocument.writeTo(fileOutputStream);
            pdfDocument.close();
        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException n) {
            n.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You create a new pdf document for every picture. For every `i`. Instead you should first add all bitmaps to the list. And when done create a pdf document.

Comment: `root.mkdir();` Check the return value of mkdir. And if false then stop and display a toast to inform the user.

Comment: Also put toasts in all catch blocks to inform the user.